# Specifying gridline positions using ggplot2

Tags: r

I've searched through here and Googled to try and find this. I'm using ggplot2 and want to specify the precise points at which my gridlines are drawn. E.g. instead of drawing a line at x = 1 I want my line at x = 1.5. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: [scale_x_continuous()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html) `scale_x_continuous(...breaks= c(...))`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `breaks` argument in `scale_x_continuous()`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:15, y = jitter(1:15, factor = 10))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 16, 1.5))
```

[image]